# Why can't we use calculus in finding the M.L.E. of Uniform(-theta, theta)?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I've understood that we use maximum/minimum of x's as MLE of theta. But no one so far has explained the reason why differentiation won't work. Please explain.

Comment: For the same reason we cannot use calculus for $U(0,\theta)$ and in general, when support of the distribution depends on the parameter of interest. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649678/how-do-you-differentiate-the-likelihood-function-for-the-uniform-distribution-in.

Comment: MLE derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795320/maximum-likelihood-estimator-for-x-1-dots-x-n-sim-u-theta-theta?rq=1).

Comment: We can use calculus. In elementary math one learns to look at critical points which include the zeros of the first derivative, if they exist, but not restricted to them.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiation won't work because the likelihood function, as a function of the parameter $\theta$, doesn't achieve its maximum where its derivative is zero.

The density function of the Uniform$[-\theta,\theta]$ distribution is
$$
f_\theta(x) =\frac1{2\theta}I(|x|\le\theta)
$$
so the likelihood function for a sample $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ is
$$
L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^nf_\theta(x_i)=\frac1{(2\theta)^n}\prod_{i=1}^n I(|x_i|\le\theta)
=\frac1{(2\theta)^n}I(\theta \ge\max_i |x_i|).
$$
The likelihood is a function of $\theta$ which is nonzero on the interval $I:=[\max_i|x_i|,\infty)$. Over this interval the function is strictly decreasing, so its derivative is never zero there. Outside of $I$ the function is zero so its maximum doesn't occur there. Thus calculus is no help in finding the maximum of $L$. On the other hand, since $L$ is nonzero and decreasing over $I$, it achieves its maximum at the left endpoint of $I$: $\hat\theta:=\max_i |x_i|$ and this is the MLE of $\theta$.