# Maximum likelihood estimator(MLE) of $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ from Uniform $(-a,a)$ distribution?

Tags: uniform-distribution, maximum-likelihood

> Find the maximum likelihood estimator(MLE) of $X_1,X_2,...,X_n\sim$ Unif $(-a,a)$.

I've tried using the likelihood function but end up getting $0$. I then tried $\max(|Xi|)$ but not sure if this is considered a maximum likelihood estimator.

Comment: The likelihood function is $$L(a;X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n) = \begin{cases}(2a)^{-n}, & \text{if } \max(|X_i| : 1 \leq i \leq n) \leq a \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Its maximum doesn't occur at $a=0$ because this will undoubtedly be in the second "otherwise" case, giving $0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum Likelihood Estimator for $\theta$ when $X_1,\dots, X_n \sim U(-\theta,\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795320/maximum-likelihood-estimator-for-theta-when-x-1-dots-x-n-sim-u-theta-t)